# Why AngularJS services get undefined while navigation from one route to the other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an issue in AngularJS. I am trying to authenticate the user and when a response got back from the server I use a service to store the user state as he is admin or not. Till now everything is fine but when I navigate from one route to the other, the service loses its data and become undefined. Any idea how to solve that?

here is the service:

```
angular.module("AccApp")

    .service('Session', function(){
        this.create = function (userName, userRole) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.userRole = userRole;
        };

        this.destroy = function () {
            this.userName = null;
            this.userRole = null;
        };

        return this;
    });
```

here is the authentication service which set the session service:

```
angular.module("AccApp")

    .factory('AuthService',['$http','$cookieStore','Session','$q', function($http, $cookieStore, Session, $q){

        var authService = {};
        var AuthentoctionControllerUrl = "http://localhost:18678/api/Authentication/";

        authService.login = function(credentials) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

           return $http.post(AuthentoctionControllerUrl, credentials).success(function(response){
               $cookieStore.put('AuthorizationHeader', response.Token);
               Session.create(response.Name, response.IsAdmin);
               deferred.resolve(response);

           }).error(function(error){

               deferred.reject(error);
           });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        authService.logout = function () {
            $cookieStore.remove('AuthorizationHeader');
        };

        authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
            if(Session.userName) return true;
            else return false;
        };

        authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRole) {
            if(authService.isAuthenticated() && authorizedRole <= Session.userRole) return true;
            else return false;
        };

        return authService;
    }]);
```

her is the log in controller.

```
angular.module("AccApp")
.controller('LoginController',['$scope','AuthService','$location', function($scope, AuthService, $location){

    $scope.credentials = {
        EmailAddress: '',
        password: ''
    };

    $scope.Login = function () {

        AuthService.login($scope.credentials).then(function(response){
            $location.path('/temp1');
        },
         function(error){
            alert("still need work");
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: sorry, but you should try to spell at least the topic correctly...

Comment: see this http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to store data while navigating between pages you can use the following code:

add it to service.js

```
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var property = null;
    return {
        getModel: function () {
            return property;
        },
        setModel: function(value) {
            property = value;
        }
    }
})
```